# How do I use strings with vectors in vectors (2D Vectors?)

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I'm trying to create a vector that has vectors inside it, but I'm dealing with `string` and `cin`

My goal is to ask the user to list out student names, and for each student listed, a vector will be created under "stuNameVecs" vector. Then these sub-vectors should hold `int` values (points received on exam) for each student, as I will later use each student's vector data to calculate the student's total grade in the class.

Example (What I need it to look like, I know that's not how you actually do it):

```
  mainVector<string> allStudents (vector<int>brendanVec, vector<int>jackVec, vector<int> johnVec)   // Elements created by .push_back
     vector<int> brendanVec(1, 5, 7, 5, 4) // Elements created by .push_back
     vector<int> jackVec(4, 2, 6, 9, 8)    // Elements created by .push_back
     vector<int> johnVec(3, 5, 6, 2, 3)    // Elements created by .push_back
```

**This is my code**

```cpp
    int main()
    {
    vector<vector<string> > stuNameVecs     // This vector is supposed to hold the vectors of each student
    int nOfStudents = 3;
    char stuName[10];

    cout << "Okay, begin by listing out the student's names:" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<nOfStudents;i++){
        cout << i+1 <<  ". ";
        cin.getline(stuName, 10);
        stuNameVecs.push_back(vector<string>); // This is where I'm getting confused. It's supposed to create a 
                                               // new vector with the student's name inside that main vector 
    }
```

Keep in mind I'm still a beginner to C++ and through all my research, I've only found examples of 2D vectors using `int` (not `string`) for data values, and `for` loops to fill up the vectors (not `.push_back`).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What method are you using to learn C++? There are a few basic mistakes you're making here and it's hard to know where to start. If you have a book or something we might be able to direct you to the correct chapter.

Comment: Barring an answer on that - your compiler is a good source of information about how code is supposed to look. The errors they spit out can be pretty arcane, but it's essential to learn how to read them, and I promise they'll stop looking like hieroglyphics eventually. What error message is your compiler giving you? Start with that one. See if you can find an answer using google and stackoverflow, and if not ask a question about that one specific error.

Comment: If you want to store the names and ints I suggest to use `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>`. Because If u want to store names and ints `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` are not valid and using  `std::vector<std::vector<std::any>>` is useless

Comment: @John What do you mean? The "Example" code is obviously not real C++, but does my actual code have problems? I know the very last line is incorrect because that's where I'm looking to get help on, but besides that, can you point out where?

Comment: Sure - missing a semicolon on your first line, which seems like a nitpick, but combined with everything else it seems relevant, using `char stuName[10]` to hold the input name when you have access to the `std::string` class instead, " for each student listed, a vector will be created under "stuNameVecs" vector" which makes me think you don't know what a `std::string` is or you don't know what a `std::vector` is.

Comment: A `std::string` is an alias for `std::basic_string<char>` which is a container that holds a sequence of `char`s. It makes more sense to store each name in a `std::string`, not in a `std::vector<std::string>`, unless you were to want to split each name on white space and store each of those tokens in its own string. But from the code it looks like you just want a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Under the section "_This is my code_" it would help if you placed code that compiled.

Comment: I *highly recommend* learning C++ from a good book on the subject. It's such a general purpose language, widely known and regarded as a ticket to a job, that there's no shortage of tutorial sites with less-than-stellar examples and curriculum. Like low-effort click-bait "news" websites, except for C++ examples.

Comment: @John Oh I see, I used `char` instead of `string` because I had to use `cin.getLine`, and that wasn't working with `string`. I couldn't figure out how to use it with `string`, if there is a way, it'd be great to know how. I see how what I'm saying is confusing, I know that a vector is basically a dynamic array that holds values. I want my code to generate new vectors named after each student, holding `int` values in each vector (inputted by the user). Sorry if my wording was confusing

Comment: On a code that compiles, this doesn't compile because I don't know how to let my code use `cin.getLine` to `.push_back` values in a vector inside of another vector. The only way my code compiles is if I don't do any of this, as I couldn't figure out how to do it

Comment: Just to rephrase what I'm trying to achieve:
User inputs: John.
Code creates the vector john inside of a main vector (could be named allStudents) that holds all the different vectors of students (which in turn hold int values for test scores)

Comment: I appreciate you going back and forth with someone who is new the language, that means a lot to me!

Comment: If you want to use `getline` to read from `cin` and put it in a `string` called `name`, you do `std::getline(std::cin, name)`. Look at the documentation for [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: So what I'm hearing is for each student, you want a `std::vector<int>` to hold the grades. And you'd like to be able to retrieve the grades based on each student by name. That sounds like you want a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: Thanks once again for not giving up on me haha, I'm not home right now, but I'll give `std::map` a try, and see if it works for me/I can figure it out. Appreciate all the help!